# SilveLight 4, System Reflection.TargetInvocationException: (Async_ExceptionOccurred)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight-4.0

I am going to try to explain this the best I can. There is a web site I need to use because of the maps, well the website have silver light which run properly. On the website there is export file option, when I pressed export button "SaveFileDialog" box appeared on the screen. Here I choose the target file path/name to copy the already exported file to my target location on my desktop. This ZIP file generates by some other service located on path like "http:Servername:81/path/File/output.zip". When I export file on the same network (Inner network) it works properly but when I accessed the same site from some other network (Outer network) I got following exception

> System Reflection.TargetInvocationException: (Async_ExceptionOccurred) 
>   Arguments:
>   Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to
>   diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60831.0&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred
>   Check InnerException for exception details. ---> System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
>      at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4(Object sendState)
>      at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(Object sendState)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>      at System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>      at NYSBridge.Utility.ArcGISLyrAndTblInfo.WebClient_OpenReadCompleted(Object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(Object arg)

Also I have placed clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files on the root of the service running on the server "http:Servername:81/path/File/output.zip" but still I am getting the exception.

Following are the entries of my clientaccesspolicy.xml & crossdomain.xml files

**clientaccesspolicy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

**crossdomain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Production environment is stuck due to this exception & I am expecting the quick response from you.

Thanks,

Zaheer

Comment: You are getting a security exception.  Are you using the same login account on both PCs (local and remove where you are uploading file)?

Comment: Yes same user/login. Same user can export the file on inner network (same network) but can't from outer network.

Comment: You have a credential issue.  Are you saying outside network user credentials will work user was inside?  Sounds like the outside network PC may not be in same group as inside PC.  I think windows is blocking the connection due to a Group Policy issue.

Comment: I am explaining the exact scenario here

Comment: 1) Same URL (like http://example.com) is being accessed with same user/Same credentials using windows authentication in both scenarios that is inner network (It means user accessed the URL on the same network for which user belongs) & outer network (The same URL is being accessed by same user from some where else outside inner network)

2) In all above scenarios, same user is being authenticated successfully (either on inner network or outer network)

Continue in below comments

Comment: 3) The issue is with the export file. When a same user access the URL on inner network, it can access  the service URL with export zip file path (deployed on some other server. Details are given in the main thread) and export the file without any error
4) At the same time, when same user access the URL from outer network, it gets the error as shared in the main thread.

I hope its clear now.

Comment: Is the folder marked as being shared so it can be accessed remotely?  Can you read File remotely?

Comment: It is not the shared folder. In fact it exists on some path which is accessible as a URL like http:Servername:81/path/File/myoutput.zip. I read this folder by creating a webclient URL. This URL/file reading works for inner network but failed for outer network with same user.
Few code snippet is below
WebClient webClient= new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (s2, e2) =>
{
    try
    {
      using (Stream fs = (Stream)this._dialog.OpenFile())
       {
          e2.Result.CopyTo(fs); // At his point exception raised
       }
    }
   catch( Exception ex)
   {
   }
}

Comment: One more thing which I want to share with you. At beginning, this code was not working for both inner/outer networks. So I have modified the client access policy & cross-domain configurations as shared in the main thread. After that this code starts working for inner network but not working for outer network.

Comment: What make you think it is NOT shared?  The url is equivalent to : \\Servername\path\File\myoutput.  I would use a windows exploer and see if you can access the file using \\Servername both local and remote and see if you get same results.

Comment: As I have shared the code snippet, I am just copying the ZIP file from URL (http:Servername:81/path/File/myoutput.zip) as a web request using webclient. This myoutput.zip file is not shared on network like \\Servername\path\File\myoutput .
Further when I paste this URL in the browser on inner network, then this zip file automatically downloads.

Comment: Is port 81 being block by firewall or virus checker?   Often port number under 1000 are automatically blocked.  Windows also has protection so remote connections are treated as guest accounts and need to be added to a group to get additional privileges.  So access to shared folders is normally blocked to guest accounts.

Comment: I have checked and port 81 is not being blocked and also users have full permissions on the folders (ZIP path).

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong.  I don't know if the server responded with an error or the issue is with the client.  The error is in the async read method and the code isn't posted.  I think the status from the response was not 200 done.  The only way of telling for sure is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and look at the http response from server.  If you are getting an status of 400 or 500 then the issue is with the server.  I would then check the event logs on the server for errors.

Comment: It seems that issue is with server not client but not sure.I will share the results after further investigation.

Comment: It could be the request is not acceptable to server.  I usually try with an IE to see if I can get the webpage to work.  If so then I modify my c# application to send same html headers as the IE.

Comment: It seems that URL (ServerName:81) is not fully qualified domain name (FQDN). I am verifying all these findings and will share with you.
I guess we should require fully qualified domain name so that it can be accessed from outer network. Am I right?

Comment: It is probably a firewall issue and/or Group Privileges.  I would talk to MIS experts at you company.  My company merged with another company and our domain name changed.  Took over 9 month to straighten out the mess.  They did it in small steps and every step things broke.